# Dictionary in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print a dictionary inside a list like this :

```
[{name : 'red', id : '1'}, {name : 'yellow', id : '2'}, {name : 'black', id : '3'}, {name : 'white', id : '4'}]`
```

I don't want quotations in `name` and `id`. However, I want them in the values portion of that dictionary.

Comment: I'm interested in the best solution to this possibly with a custom Encoder class or without having to do anything hacky

Comment: the question is **why** - if you're trying to make it into Javascript, then this might be not enough.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'd have to write your own formatting function to do that.

Here's a hairy but terse function that does what you want:

```
def pretty_print(data):
    return '[%s]' % ', '.join(
        '{%s}' % ', '.join(
            '%s : %r' % (key, value) for key, value in item.items()
        ) for item in data
    )
```

So the following code:

```
print(pretty_print([
    {'name': 'red', 'id': '1'},
    {'name': 'yellow', 'id': '2'},
]))
```

Would print:

```
[{name : 'red', id : '1'}, {name : 'yellow', id : '2'}]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can convert this like:

#### Code:

```
def fix_key_formatting(data_to_dump, keys_to_fix):
    return_str = json.dumps(data_to_dump)
    for key in keys_to_fix:
        return_str = return_str.replace('"%s":' % key, '%s:' % key)
    return return_str
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = [
    {'name': 'red', 'id': '1'},
    {'name': 'yellow', 'id': '2'},
    {'name': 'black', 'id': '3'},
    {'name': 'white', 'id': '4'}
]

import json
print(fix_key_formatting(data, ('id', 'name')))
```

#### Results:

```
[
    {name: "red", id: "1"}, 
    {name: "yellow", id: "2"}, 
    {name: "black", id: "3"}, 
    {name: "white", id: "4"}
]
```

Comment: I'm sorry the list also asks like :

Answer (score 4):

You can create a simple class with a `__repr__` method to store the string value:

```
class String:
   def __init__(self, val):
      self.val = val
   def __repr__(self):
      return self.val
data = [{'name' : 'red', 'id' : '1'}, {'name' : 'yellow', 'id' : '2'}, {'name' : 'black', 'id' : '3'}, {'name' : 'white', 'id' : '4'}]
final_data = [{String(c):d for c, d in i.items()} for i in data]
```

Output:

```
[{name: 'red', id: '1'}, {name: 'yellow', id: '2'}, {name: 'black', id: '3'}, {name: 'white', id: '4'}]
```

To access the string values, you can call the attribute:

```
string_values = [{c.val:d for c, d in i.items()} for i in final_data]
```

To apply the class `String` to all keys in an arbitrary structure, recursion can be used:

```
def convert_string(d):
   return {String(a):convert_string(b) if isinstance(b, dict) else b for a, b in d.items()}

data = [{'name' : {'first':'blue', 'last':'black', 'known_ids':[34, 5, 12, 34]}, 'id' : '1'}, {'name' : 'yellow', 'id' : '2'}, {'name' : 'black', 'id' : '3'}, {'name' : 'white', 'id' : '4'}]
new_data = list(map(convert_string, data))
```

Output:

```
[{name: {first: 'blue', last: 'black', known_ids: [34, 5, 12, 34]}, id: '1'}, {name: 'yellow', id: '2'}, {name: 'black', id: '3'}, {name: 'white', id: '4'}]
```

Comment: I like the general direction this is going, i think it would be complete if it could be integrated into `json` custom Encoder class and i know you can change the representation for a custom type. Then if we wanted to be the canonical approach, we could just make it recursively traverse all the dictionaries and replace them with `String` class. But I'm happy with this approach as it stands cause its enough to extend from

Comment: The problem with integrating `json` module is that keys must be string, maybe there's some way around it

Answer (score 2):

Here is another not so elegant but functional solution:

```
inList = [{'name' : 'red', 'id' : '1'}, {'name' : 'yellow', 'id' : '2'}, {'name' : 'black', 'id' : '3'}, {'name' : 'white', 'id' : '4'}]

def getDictFormatted(inDict):
    return "{" + ", ".join(k + " : " + repr(v) for k,v in inDict.items()) + "}"

def printListFormatted(inList):
    output = "[" + ", ".join(getDictFormatted(d) for d in inList) + "]"
    print(output)

printListFormatted(inList)
```

Output:

```
[{id : '1', name : 'red'}, {id : '2', name : 'yellow'}, {id : '3', name : 'black'}, {id : '4', name : 'white'}]
```